# Generate a Unique Sequential ID VS2008

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to generate a sequential unique ID that is tied with the QuizTitle in my database. I wanted to start with number 1 and it will increment based on whether it's a new QuizTitle or not. I don't know what's wrong with my code but it is not showing me anything:

```
Private Sub QuizID()
    Dim myReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    AConn.Open()
    Dim temp As String
    Try
        Dim sql As String = "Select COUNT(*) as numRows FROM tblQuestions where QuizTitle = '" & frmStudReg.txtPD_UN.Text & "'"
        Dim comm As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, AConn)
        myReader = comm.ExecuteReader
        If myReader.HasRows Then
            While myReader.Read()
                temp = myReader.Item("QuizID") + 1
            End While
        End If
        myReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    AConn.Close()
   Me.txtNewQuiz_QuizID.Text = String.Concat(temp)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all you are getting in your query is the count of items, try to use `ExecuteScalar` as follows:

```
' Assuming you've created the command already, I'm just setting the text here. You can do it via the constructor as you had done if you wish.
comm.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblQuestions WHERE QuizTitle = @QuizTitle"
comm.Parameters.Add("@QuizTitle", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
comm.Parameters("@QuizTitle").Value = frmStudReg.txtPD_UN.Text 
Dim count As Integer = comm.ExecuteScalar()
```

At this point, you can then use `count` as you wish. Note also that I used parameters instead of string concatenation to build the query. You are opening yourself up to sql injection if you take input from a user or external source and use that to build a query.